# asmx .net 2.0 web service

Tags: .net-2.0, service, asmx

i created a web service, upload it to my site on a remote server.
i tried to browse it but i cant, i also tried to add web reference to his adress through vs08 but the same problem happened there.

Comment: it all depends on what you mean by cant - please post the error you recieved from the webserver

Comment: You need to give us more details than that.   Did you get any errors?  What errors did you encounter.  Please provide the error text and some details...

Comment: Also, please post the service name space as found in the file with the service code, and tell us how you deployed it.

Comment: i didnt get any errors, only when beowsing it i get a 404 page not found error,
the name space is "http://www.poppetz.com/poppetz" but the service is actually in
http://www.popetz.co.il/Services/Poppetz.asmx
maybe this is the problem???

i deployed it with vs08 through ftp

Comment: http://www.popetz.co.il/Services/Poppetz.asmx gives a .NET framework error.  Try adjusting your web.config to show errors, or just browse to this url on the local machine (if you have access)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10x everyone, the server provider change some iis config and everything works...\

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on your comment:

> i didnt get any errors, only when
>   beowsing it i get a 404 page not found
>   error, the name space is
>   "http://www.poppetz.com/poppetz"; but
>   the service is actually in
>   http://www.popetz.co.il/Services/Poppetz.asmx
>   maybe this is the problem??? i
>   deployed it with vs08 through ftp –
>   Chen Kinnrot (2 mins ago)

The namespace of your service will have nothing to do with you being able to access it.

If you put a plain old test.html that echo "hello world" back to you and put that in the same directory as your service, can you access that?
ie: http://www.popetz.co.il/Services/test.html

Can you get access to the machine hosting the web services.  If so, if you look in the IIS manager, can you see the ASMX in the web site you are expecting it be in?

If not, then start looking at the IIS configuration and make sure that web site directory is the same folder as you are dumping the web service files.

Comment: i tried the test page and the browsing works u can see it in
http://www.popetz.co.il/Services/testPage.htm

Comment: Is the ASP.Net ISAPI enabled?  
Is the web site configured to use .Net 2.0?